# Global implicit syle on the type Control in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles, global, implicit

This style should apply on every control, but it has no effect, WHY?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />           
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is incorrect. Implicit Styles are only applied to the specified type, not to types that derive from it.

For example, assume you have a custom button like:

```
public class MyButton : Button {
    // ...
}
```

And an implicit Style like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />           
</Style>
```

In the following XMAL, the Style above would not affect MyButton:

```
<Grid>
    <Button />
    <local:MyButton />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes right after I posted that I realized there is no type Control in my app just the child controls from base Control.